# Finding an analytic function $g(z)$ satisfying an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic and does not vanish in  an open region containing $|z|< 1$ and for some $M>0,$
$\Re\frac{zf'(z)}{(Mf(z))}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $z$ for which $f(z)\neq 0$ on $|z|=1.$ Can we find a function $g(z)$ analytic in $|z|\leq 1$ with $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|\leq 1$ and  $g(0)=0$ such that on $|z|=1,$ $M|f(z)|\leq |1+g(z)|\max_{|z|=1}|f'(z)|?$

Motivation: $\Re\frac{zf'(z)}{(Mf(z))}\geq \frac{1}{2}$ on $|z|=1$ implies $2|f'(z)|\geq M|f(z)|.$

Answer (score 1):

It is true for polynomials it seems. If $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ having no zeros in $|z|<1,$ then Tur'an's inequality is  $\Re \frac{zf'(z)}{nf(z)}\geq \frac{1}{2}.$ So if $h(z)=z^n\overline{f(1/\overline{z})},$ then on $|z|=1,$
$$n|f(z)|=n|h(z)|=|nh(z)-zh'(z)+zh'(z)|=|nh(z)-zh'(z)|\left|1+\frac{zh'(z)}{nh(z)-zh'(z)}\right|=|f'(z)|\left|1+g(z)\right|,$$ where $g(z)=\frac{zh'(z)}{nh(z)-zh'(z)}$ is analytic in $|z|<1$ and it can be checked that $|{zh'(z)}|\leq |{nh(z)-zh'(z)}|$ on $|z|=1.$ Further $g(0)=0.$

When $M=n,$ it is possible. But for any $M$ I do not have answer as of now.